# Layout is not working in order update email template

Tags: magento2, email

I tried below, but am not getting that order items layout handle,I put that layout handle in end..please help.

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!--@subject Your {{var store.getFrontendName()}} order has shipped @-->
<!--@vars {
"var formattedBillingAddress|raw":"Billing Address",
"var order.getEmailCustomerNote()":"Email Order Note",
"var order.increment_id":"Order Id",
"layout handle=\"sales_email_order_items\" order=$order area=\"frontend\"":"Order Items Grid",
"var payment_html|raw":"Payment Details",
"var formattedShippingAddress|raw":"Shipping Address",
"var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description"
} @-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">{{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order.getCustomerName()}}</p>
            <p>
                {{trans
                    "Your order #%increment_id has been updated with a status of <strong>%order_status</strong>."
                    increment_id=$order.increment_id
                    order_status=$order.getStatusLabel()
                |raw}}

                {{trans "Thank you for your order from %store_name." store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}}

                {{trans 'You can check the status of your order by <a href="%account_url">logging into your account</a>.' account_url=$this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/',[_nosid:1]) |raw}}
            </p>
            <p>
                {{trans 'If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>.' store_email=$store_email |raw}}
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="email-summary">
        <td>
            <h1>Order Shipped!</h1>
            <h1>{{trans 'Your Order <span class="no-link">#%increment_id</span>' increment_id=$order.increment_id |raw}}</h1>
            <p>{{trans 'Placed on <span class="no-link">%created_at</span>' created_at=$order.getCreatedAtFormatted(1) |raw}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>
            {{depend order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
            <table class="message-info">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()|escape|nl2br}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/depend}}
            <table class="order-details">
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Billing Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="method-info">
                         {{depend shipping_arrival_date}}
                            <h3>{{trans "Order Delivery Date"}}</h3>
                            <p>{{var shipping_arrival_date}}</p>
                        {{/depend}}

                           {{depend shipping_delivered_date}}
                                 <h3>{{trans "Actual Ship Date"}}</h3>
                                 <p>{{var shipping_delivered_date}}</p>
                           {{depend shipping_delivered_date}}


                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Method"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    {{depend carrier_name}}
                      <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipped By"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var carrier_name}}</p>
                      </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                    {{depend carrier_name}}
                        <td class="method-info">
                           <h3>{{trans "Tracking Number"}}</h3>
                            <p>{{var tracing_number}}</p>
                        </td>
                    {{/depend}} 

                </tr>

               <tr>
                    {{depend shipping_arrival_comments}}
                      <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Order Comment"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var shipping_arrival_comments}}</p>
                      </td>
                    {{/depend}}


                </tr>



            </table>
                 {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Comment: Have you solved it ? I too have same issue , if you have a solution could you update?